# Why would my MySQL replica server experience an sql integrity constraint error after losing connection and attempting to start again?

Tags: replication, mariadb, disaster-recovery, master-master-replication, magento

I have a master-master replication setup between two different servers using MariaDB. One is the primary server (server A) that is connected to my web applications, and the other is a replica that would be used for disaster recovery if the primary one was down (server B). Awhile back I shut down server B rather abruptly for about 5 minutes so that I could resize it, but when I brought it back up, I received an SQL integrity constraint violation error that prevented replication from starting back up.

I ended up rebuilding server B from a backup of server A later down the road and started replication back up successfully.

My question is: Why would this connection issue have caused an integrity constraint error? I thought that it would be able to simply pick up from the log file position that it stopped reading from. I’m trying to figure out so that, in the future, if server B loses connection for whatever reason, that I’m able to recover from it instead of having to rebuild the database.

Comment: Elaborate on "rather abruptly".  Are you using MyISAM for any of your tables?  I'm not familiar with the phrase "SQL integrity constraint violation error"; I don't think it came from MariaDB; do you know where it comes from?

Comment: I shut the whole cloud server down from my host’s web label, rather than going in and stopping the MySQL service with a systemctl terminal command. I basically pressed the big red shutdown button. I believe the proper error term was “integrity constraint violation”, not “error”. That was the error message that showed up when I attempted to run `start slave` again and did `show slave status\G`. All of the tables in the database in question are InnoDB tables.

Comment: I do remember that the error was related to some sort of "session" table from a Magento install. I wish that I had the error still so that I could read it again in full, but I did not have it writing to a log at the time and it was quite a bit ago. I know this might not be enough information to answer the question, but I wanted to see if there was some idea behind how this could have happened logically.